# Problem popup / quick fix popup - set disappear delay

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way in VS Code to make the problem popup / quick fix popup disappear after some delay?

All I have found in the settings is to increase the delay *after* all kinds of popups appear. Nothing about disappearing.

[image: Disapearing popup]

Comment: Even in 2023, being able to press the quick fix button seems to be a dexterity challenge that can be problematic even for career gamers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just found out that this is tracked on the VS Code issue tracker [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/147403) and planned for August 2022. But it was already rescheduled 3 times, so...